# Ejs forEach loop is not defined

Tags: arrays, node.js, express, foreach, ejs

So here is my problem I am trying to do a forEach in ejs which will render html onto the page. Here is the store page for the ejs forEach loop.

```
<% include _includes/header.ejs %>
   <div class="container">
     <% cards.forEach( card => { %>
      <% include('_includes/cards.ejs', card) %>
  <% }) %>
</div>
<% include _includes/footer.ejs %>
```

here is the cards.ejs file

```
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
  <img class="card-img-top" src='' alt="Card image cap">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title"><%= titleCard %></h5>
    <p class="card-text"><%= desc %></p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my express code for the store page

```
 app.get('/store', function(req, res) {
  res.render('store', {
    user: req.user,
    title: 'Store'});
});
```

and finally this

```
cards = [
  {
    titleCard: 'title 1',
    desc: 'just some text'
  },
  {
    titleCard: 'title 1',
    desc: 'just some text'
  },
  {
    titleCard: 'title 1',
    desc: 'just some text'
  },
]
```

I have tried multiple things and always get the error **that cards is not defined**. Where am I supposed to put this? I would really appreciate some help on this!

Comment: You don't show your Express code, but you have to pass `cards` to `res.render()` so that EJS has the data when it tries to render the page.  Any basic example of using EJS with Express should show you how you pass data to be used in the rendering the template.

Comment: @jfriend00 I have updated my post with the express code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to pass `cards` to `res.render()`.   You can do so like this:

```
app.get('/store', function(req, res) {
  res.render('store', {
    user: req.user,
    title: 'Store',
    cards: cards
  });
});
```

Comment: I'm not an EJS expert so I can't comment on whether your EJS templates are designed correctly, but this is how you pass data to any of the Express-compatible template engines which is what I think you were asking.

Comment: Right, and so I just export the cards array from another js file?

Comment: @Zack - If it's declared or created in another file, then you will have to import it into where you call `res.render()` because that's where you need it.

Comment: Yeah, I used module.exports and I had a typo. I copied and pasted another export that I had imported and forgot to change the name. However, I am now getting a new error saying that **cards.forEach is not a function**

Comment: @Zack - That sounds like `cards` is not an array.  I can't really debug code I can't see, but it appears that `cards` is now defined, but isn't an array.

Comment: here is my module.exports
`module.exports = {
 cards: [
   {
     titleCard: 'some text',
     desc: 'Some description'
   },
   {
     titleCard: 'some text2',
     desc: 'Some description2'
   }
 ]
};`

Comment: I have got the error to go away by including `<% var cards = Array.from(cards) %>`
I logged in to the console and it returns empty an empty array

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of things that may help,

1- Make sure you're exporting this cards module in a proper way, basically you cannot just import it without an explicit export.

2- Try to use an object parameter to the include method

```
<% include('_includes/cards.ejs', {card : card}) %>
```

I apologize, I can't test it right now, but try this and let me know if it worked.

Comment: I believe I did what you said but it did not work. I really don't know what the problem is.

Comment: @Zack - I'm guessing that you're not doing your export and import properly.  Please show the exact code that is exporting the `cards` array and show the code that imports it and show the `res.render()` line of code you're using.  You can add these to the end of your question.